# Updating a graph/plot by looping over a list using matplotlib or seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have a list of 5000 elements. Each element of this list has 2 separate lists (let's say x and y) in it with 128 variables each. Now I want to plot 5000 lines of x and y in the same graph. The list is of the following form:

```
my_list = [
    [[1_a1,1_a2,1_a3...,1_a128],[1_b1,1_b2,1_b3...,1_b128]], 
    [[2_a1,2_a2,2_a3...,2_a128],[2_b1,2_b2,2_b3...,2_b128]],
    ......,
    [[5000_a1,5000_a2,5000_a3...,5000_a128],[5000_b1,5000_b2,5000_b3...,5000_b128]]
]
```

I have tried using matplotlib but I am getting 5000 separate plots, however, I need 5000 lines in one plot

```
for i in range(0,len(empty),1): #empty is my_list
 fig1 = plt.figure()
 plt.plot(empty[i][0],empty[i][1], 'r', linewidth=1) 
 plt.grid(True) 
 plt.xlabel('Heat flow in kW')
 plt.ylabel('Temperature in C') 
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you provide what you've tried to plot your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Since you haven't posted code I'll be guessing *a bit* here, but</strike> consider using the following to plot those 5000 lines on one graph:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# my_list: contains data described above
for sub_list in my_list:
    x = np.array(sub_list[0])
    y = np.array(sub_list[1])
    plt.plot(x, y)

plt.show()
```